# bitcoind is not downloading blockchain

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind

I have installed bitcoind on Ubuntu Server. It didn't download a single block

```
bitcoind getblockcount
```

This returns 0 everytime I run.
Here is bitcoind getinfo

```
{
    "version" : 80500,
    "protocolversion" : 70001,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 0.00000000,
    "blocks" : 0,
    "timeoffset" : 0,
    "connections" : 0,
    "proxy" : "127.0.0.1:9050",
    "difficulty" : 1.00000000,
    "testnet" : false,
    "keypoololdest" : 1385148166,
    "keypoolsize" : 101,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "errors" : ""
}
```

Comment: have removed proxy its downloading now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have removed proxy its downloading now

Comment: You can accept your own answer; otherwise this keeps bouncing to the top of the list as "unanswered".